# How to filter list objects by field value in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Say I have the following json data:

```json
"data": {
    "continents": [
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "name": "Africa",
        },
        {
            "code": "EU",
            "name": "Europe"
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

What would be the correct GraphQL query to fetch a list item with:  `code : "AF"`? In other words, how to produce the following result:

```json
"data": {
    "code": "AF",
    "name": "Africa"
}
```

---

So far, I have:

```
query {
  continents {
    code
    name
  }
}
```

but that simply returns the full array.

I've been running my examples on: https://lucasconstantino.github.io/graphiql-online/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this current example you can just do

```
query {
  continents(filter: {code: {eq: "AF"}}) {
    name
  }
}
```

I'd suggest to review the [documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) regarding arguments since they explain it quite well.

Comment: Wait a minute, I am not using any variables. And I could find no mention of `filter` nor `eq` in the docs. That said, your query somewhat answers my question.

Comment: corrected my answer, hope this clarifies, arguments is what is used here, mixed those two up.
there is a filter argument that is passed in the graphql function and in the backend dal they use this argument to filter

Answer (score 27):

As it turns out, there is no built-in `filter` function defined on lists/arrays! *GraphQL (query language) is basically about selecting **fields** on **objects*** [[Schemas and Types | GraphQL]](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/).

One only needs to look at the [GraphQL schema in question](http://countries.trevorblades.com/):

```
type Query {
  continents(filter: ContinentFilterInput): [Continent!]!
  // ...
}
type Continent {
  code: ID!
  name: String!
  countries: [Country!]!
}
input ContinentFilterInput {
  code: StringQueryOperatorInput
}
input StringQueryOperatorInput {
  eq: String
  ne: String
  in: [String]
  nin: [String]
  regex: String
  glob: String
}
// ...
```

We see that query `continents` has a parameter `filter` of input type `ContinentFilterInput`. That's enough information for us to start building our filter query:

```
query {
  continents(filter: ...) {
    code
    name
  }
}
```

Upon inspecting `ContinentFilterInput`, we observe that it has a single field `code` of input type `StringQueryOperatorInput`:

```
query {
  continents(filter: { code: ...}) {
    code
    name
  }
}
```

Finally, we find a field `eq` inside input type `StringQueryOperatorInput` which is a scalar type (`String`) and we are done:

```
query {
  continents(filter: { code: { eq: "AF" } }) {
    code
    name
  }
}
```